# How to find nodes and levels in a given string of brackets?

Tags: javascript, c#, python

I've an input string with brackets like below.

[[[[[]]]][[[]]]][]

I need to find out how many nodes([]) can be created and how many parent and child levels we can arrange brackets in the string.

Example: [[[[][[[]]]][][][[]]]][[[[][]]]] Number of Nodes = 16 Number of levels = 6

I tried an approach of finding the start and end indexes of "[" , "]" and counted the numbers of it. If both are equal, then I added the index to count. The summation gives me the node count.

But I'm stuck in finding the levels.

```
for(int i=0;i<sth.Length;i++)
                {
                    if(sth[i]=='[')
                    {
                        count1++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count2++;
                    }
                    if (count1 == count2)
                    {

                        numOfNodes += count1;
                        count1 = 0;
                        count2 = 0;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more about Algorithm than programming, but a simple method that you can try is to use stacks like following steps.

1. Create an index.
2. Traverse the string, do following for every character

   - If current character is `[` push one item to the index.
   - If character is `]`, pop an item.
   - Maintain the maximum value of the index during the traversal.

After finishing the traverse  the maximum value represents the levels.
here is the `c#` code for your example:

```
    string sampple = "[[[[][[[]]]][][][[]]]][[[[][]]]]";
    int levels = 0;
    int index = 0;

    foreach (char c in sampple)
    {
        if (c == '[')
            index++;

        if (c == ']')
            index--;

        if (index >= levels)
            levels = index;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Levels: " + levels);
```

which outputs:

> Levels: 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```js
const str = "[[[[][[[]]]][][][[]]]][[[[][]]]]";


const maxlevel = getMaxLevel(str);
const nodesLength = getNodesLength(str);
console.log(maxlevel, 'level');
console.log(nodesLength, 'nodes');

function getMaxLevel(str) {
  const arr = str.match(/\[+/g);
  if (arr) {
    arr.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length);
    return arr[0].length;  
  }
}

function getNodesLength(str) {
  let counter = 0;
  while (/\[\]/.test(str)) {
    counter++;
    str = str.replace(/\[\]/, '');
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the code above? I mean the maxlevel part. If the [ count is taken by regex, will it be correct always?

Comment: Basically, what it does is to extract one or more groups of "[" eg ["[[[[", "[[", "["]. And it will simply sort the array from highest to lowest frequency of "["